# Extract zip MemoryStream to string

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I am using [DotNetZip Library](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) to save *MemoryStream* to .xml data and read its text form saved loacation:

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(myMs))
{
   zip[0].Extract(@"C:\XmlFilePath\MyXml.xml", ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
}
```

Is there any way to read Xml string on extracting without saving it in file or temp file using this library? Please Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get a stream from `zip[0].OpenReader()` and read your string from that.

Comment: Thanks perfectly worked, is it possible to convert XmlDocument object zipstream using same library?

Comment: For the Zip library XML is just text. As long as you use the same library for packing and unpacking it should work.